# How does one search across application insight analytics tables?

Tags: azure-application-insights

I'd like to search for all analytics for a given operation_id in Application Insights Analytics without having to specify each table (request, dependencies, exceptions, traces, etc.). I recall that there is some way that doesn't prompt in intellisense, but unable to locate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
union *
| where operation_Id == "<id>"
| take 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also found that the following works as well:

```
search *
| where operation_Id =="<Id>"
```

*I'll update with my source once I figure out where I found this*